# How to parse comments / documentation in Groovy code?

Tags: parsing, groovy

I'd like to parse the JavaDocs / GroovyDocs in my Groovy source code and build a JSON file with the parts that I'm interested in. Is there a clean way of doing this? I'd like to retrieve the class docs, field docs, method docs, etc. Example:

```
/** Please parse me. */
class Foo { /** And me too */ def prop }
```

One of the responses in the following thread was helpful in mentinoing GroovyDocTool / GroovyLexer / GroovyRecognizer, but I could really use a concrete example of how to add my own custom parsing: [How to parse groovy code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354165/how-to-parse-groovy-code)

**My current workaround** is to attempt parsing the HTML that the "groovydoc" and "grails doc" commands generate. I'll probably try using NekoHTML to convert the HTML into well-formed XML, then use XmlSlurper. See: http://www.codercorp.com/blog/groovy/reading-html-using-groovys-xmlslurper.html

Answer (score 0):

You may try [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) and create a parser. But this will be a brand new parser you may have to write